# How can an ngrx feature selector be unit tested in Jasmine with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, ngrx

I have a feature selector and adjacent selectors for my **products** feature:

```
const getProductState = createFeatureSelector<fromProducts.State>('products');

export const getOldProducts = createSelector(
    getProductState,
    state => state.oldProducts
);

export getNewProducts = createSelector(
    getProductState,
    state => state.newProducts
);
```

I want to unit test against these selectors.  Most articles and posts I read only deal with non-feature selectors, so come time to mock the feature state, my tests are returning `undefined` for the state object.  My spec file looks like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            StoreModule.forRoot({}),
            StoreModule.forFeature('products', fromProduct.reducer)
        ],
        declarations: [],
        providers: [{
            provide: Store, useClass: class { select = jasmine.createSpy('select'); dispatch = jasmine.createSpy('dispatch'); }
        }]
    })
    mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);
}));

it('getOldProducts should return the oldProducts', () => {
    const state = {
        name: 'Product1',
        oldProduct: {
            price: 45.00
        },
        newProduct: {
            price: 50.00
        }
    }: fromProduct.State;
    expect(selectors.getOldProducts(state.oldProducts)).toBe(state.oldProducts);
});
```

Error keeps saying `Cannot read property 'oldProducts' of undefined`, which leads me to believe the `getProductState` feature selector isn't being mocked properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and this thread helped me. Although the solution is not clear.

You need to use the `projector` function from the selector as @J-man said.
For your case would be:

`expect(selectors.getOldProducts.projector(state.oldProducts)).toBe(state.oldProducts);`

Comment: it was this current thread, mainly the @J-MAN reply to the solution below. I gave him the credit on my response :) Sorry for not being specific on which threat I was referring to

Answer (score 2):

Because the feature selector is selecting `products` from the store state, you'll have to create the global state.

```
const state = {
  products: {
    name: 'Product1',
    oldProduct: {
      price: 45.00
    },
    newProduct: {
      price: 50.00
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I do that?  Is it in the `imports: [ StoreModule ]` area or inject the data into the store outside of the `TestBed`?

Comment: I found the `projector` function gets met what I am after.  Not sure if this is the preferred or best way to go about testing selectors, but my test looks like: `expect(selectors.getOldProducts.projector(state)).toBe(state.oldProducts);` where I am also setting a global `state` object before each test.

Comment: Using the projection function is fine. It lets you to only setup the state you are interested in instead of the whole state.

Comment: To answer your first comment, everything is the same except for the state you define. You have to define your whole appstate, and your product state with a products property.